# Windows Server Use Ip address on iPhone

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I've a windows server. I need to be able to use its IP address to connect to the internet via my iPhone. I don't know if I've to set up a proxy on the server or if it's possible to use SOCKS and do a [SSH Tunneling](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/dedicated-virtual-server-internet-proxy-ssh-tunneling/), as with linux. Do you've any suggestion on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Where is the iPhone? Is it on the same local network as the server, or are you wanting to do this from anywhere in the world?

Comment: The Server is a datacenter somewhere, the iPhone is with me... so I guess it's not on the same network

Answer (score 3):

Setup an IPSec VPN via [Routing and Remote Access](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771052(v=ws.10).aspx) on your Windows Server.

Then if you [connect to the VPN from your phone](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201533), the iPhone's internet traffic will route through the server.